# Read csv file into list of lists without string convertion in Python

Tags: python, string, list, file, csv

I have got a car.csv, which has lines like this:

```
vhigh,vhigh,2,2,small,low,unacc
```

I want to get:

```
[vhigh,vhigh,2,2,small,low,unacc].
```

But with this code

```
import csv
a = []
with open("car.csv", 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in f:
        a.append([line]);
```

I get

```
['vhigh,vhigh,2,2,small,med,unacc\n'].
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: I wasn't aware that [vhigh,vhigh,2,2,small,low,unacc] is the same as ['vhigh','vhigh','2','2','small','low','unacc']

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create the reader, iterate over that instead of over the file so do:

```
for line in reader:
    a.append(line)
```

or if you just want all the lines as a list

```
a = list(reader)
```

putting that all together:

```
with open("car.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    a = list(reader)
```

Answer (score -1):

Split the content of the line

```
line.split(',')
```

Comment: What if one of the fields in the CSV contains a comma?